# Struts 2.1.6 Upgradation with Websphere 7 Server

Tags: struts2, websphere

I am trying to deploy the Struts - 2.1.6 application on Websphere 7.0.27 server. I have enabled the security for the LDAP authentication. When I try to run the application, I am getting following error message :

> [3/20/14 12:51:21:086 MDT] 00000017 SystemOut O 2014-03-20 12:51:21,086 WARN    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder - Unable to load config class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor at interceptor** - wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvHSCS/installedApps/IBM-7eee9b3778eNode02Cell/acys-hscs.ear/acys-hscs-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:146:127 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the validation interceptor
>   [3/20/14 12:51:21:093 MDT] 00000017 SystemOut O 2014-03-20 12:51:21,089 ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder - **Actual exception
>   Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor - interceptor - wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvHSCS/installedApps/IBM-7eee9b3778eNode02Cell/acys-hscs.ear/acys-hscs-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar!/struts-default.xml:146:127

Comment: Please use *at least* Struts 2.3.16, due to security issues

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the DTD declaration in your validation xml files is accurate (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177112/struts2-annotationvalidationinterceptor)).

Comment: I am using following DTD declaration in my validation.xml file

<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">